# Javascript FizzBuzz and Behavior-Driven Development Using Mocha and Chai

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, fizzbuzz, bdd

I am currently getting closely acquainted with [Behavior-Driven Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development). Could someone tell me how I am doing with the Fizzbuzz program below? I am interested in both improving the JavaScript code and the BDD prowess. Any help is appreciated.

fizzbuzz.js

```
module.exports = function(word, value){   
    function sortNumber(a,b) {
        return a - b;
    }
    
    numbers = function(divisor, max){
        var result = []
        for(i=1;i<=max;i++){
            if ((i % divisor) === 0)
                result.push(i)
        }
        return result
    }
    
    if (value <= 0)
        return ['error','nonpositive']
        
    else {
        switch(word) {
            case 'fizz':
                return numbers(3, value)
            case 'buzz':
                return numbers(5,value)
            case 'fizzbuzz':
                return numbers(3,value).concat(numbers(5,value)).filter(function(elem,index,self){
                        return index == self.indexOf(elem)
                    }).sort(sortNumber)
            default:
                return ['error','wrongword']
        }
    }
};
```

test/fizzbuzz-spec.js:

```
var chai = require('chai');
    expect = chai.expect,
    fizzbuzz = require('../lib/fizzbuzz');
    
describe('A fizzbuzz', function(){
    describe('will return an error for invalid words: ', function(){
        it('like fuss', function(){
            expect(fizzbuzz('fuss', 10)).to.be.deep.equal(['error','wrongword']);
        });
        it('like biss', function(){
            expect(fizzbuzz('biss', 10)).to.be.deep.equal(['error','wrongword']);
        });
    });
    
    describe('will return an error when non-positive integer is passed', function(){
        it('like 0', function(){
            expect(fizzbuzz('buzz', 0)).to.be.deep.equal(['error','nonpositive']);
        })
        it('like -2', function(){
            expect(fizzbuzz('buzz', -2)).to.be.deep.equal(['error','nonpositive']);
        })
    })
    
    describe('will return valid non-error input when positive integers and valid words are passed', function(){
        it('like fizz and 20', function(){
            expect(fizzbuzz('fizz', 20)).not.to.contain('error');
        })
        it('like buzz and 20', function(){
            expect(fizzbuzz('buzz', 20)).not.to.contain('error');
        })
        it('like fizzbuzz and 20', function(){
            expect(fizzbuzz('fizzbuzz', 20)).not.to.contain('error');
        })      
    })
    
    describe('will return valid results for some basic valid test cases', function(){
        it('like fizz and 10', function(){
            expect(fizzbuzz('fizz', 10)).to.be.deep.equal([3,6,9]);
        })
        it('like fizz and 20', function(){
            expect(fizzbuzz('fizz', 20)).to.be.deep.equal([3,6,9,12,15,18]);
        })
        it('like buzz and 10', function(){
            expect(fizzbuzz('buzz', 10)).to.be.deep.equal([5,10]);
        })
        it('like buzz and 25', function(){
            expect(fizzbuzz('buzz', 25)).to.be.deep.equal([5,10,15,20,25]);
        })
        it('like fizzbuzz and 10', function(){
            expect(fizzbuzz('fizzbuzz', 10)).to.be.deep.equal([3,5,6,9,10]);
        })
        it('like fizzbuzz and 25', function(){
            expect(fizzbuzz('fizzbuzz', 25)).to.be.deep.equal([3,5,6,9,10,12,15,18,20,21,24,25]);
        })
        it('like fizz and 2', function(){
            expect(fizzbuzz('fizz', 2)).to.be.deep.equal([]);
        })
        it('like buzz and 4', function(){
            expect(fizzbuzz('buzz', 4)).to.be.deep.equal([]);
        })
        
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

### Handling invalid input

Instead of returning an array when inputs are invalid, [throw exceptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) and use [`throw`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw) to detect it in the tests.

### Avoid `else` when previous blocks have return statements

The `else` can be eliminated since the block evaluated when `value <= 0` has a return statement (or would `throw` an exception). Additionally, the `switch` statement can be simplified to a few `if` statements (for an example see [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/211122/120114) to a related question).

### Don't forget to set scopes

While the code is in a module, it is best to set the scope of variables and functions - e.g. `numbers` and `i` in the loop within `numbers` should be prefixed by the keywords `const` and `let`, respectively, to avoid accidental re-assignment/confusion.

In that same vein, the first few lines of the test are setting variables:

> ```
> var chai = require('chai');
>     expect = chai.expect,
>     fizzbuzz = require('../lib/fizzbuzz');
> ```

Perhaps you meant to add a comma instead of semi-colon after `require('chai')`? It would be simpler just to have each variable on its own line:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const fizzbuzz = require('../lib/fizzbuzz');
```

Actually instead of importing `chai` just to use `expect` from it on a separate line, use object-destructuring:

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
const fizzbuzz = require('../lib/fizzbuzz');
```